# Android - Changing ActionBar's icons dynamically to fit the theme (dark/light)

Tags: android-layout, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-theme, android-icons

I have an app which has multiple themes, some of them are "light" themes and some are "dark".

In my actionbar I have mutiple icons, which I've downloaded as PNGs from [Google's material icons website](https://material.io/icons/).

**Questions:**

1. How do I change them to be black/white according to the theme?
2. If the answer is to use vectors, how still do I make them change color? Would vector icons affect performance?

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution?